# retrieved upload images in php

Tags: php

i want to retrieve image from client (ipod) programmed in objective c i use the following code

```
$TARGET_PATH = "pics/";
$image = $_FILES['photo'];
$TARGET_PATH =$TARGET_PATH . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);
$TARGET_PATH =$TARGET_PATH.".jpg";
if(file_exists($TARGET_PATH))
    {
$TARGET_PATH =$TARGET_PATH .uniqid() . ".jpg";
}
if (move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], $TARGET_PATH))
{
    $TARGET_PATH="http://www.".$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]."/abc/".$TARGET_PATH;
        echo $TARGET_PATH;
        echo "image upload successfully";}
else{
    echo "could not upload image";
}
```

this code upload five to six images successfully and after that it gives me error i.e

```
Notice:  Undefined index:  photo in /home/abc/public_html/abc.com/fish/mycatch_post.php on line 42

Notice:  Undefined index:  photo in /home/abc/public_html/abc.com/fish/mycatch_post.php on line 53

could not upload image
```

Comment: Start with making test outputs of `TARGET_PATH` , and do a `print_r($_FILES);` to find out whether anything gets uploaded in the first place

Comment: yes it uploads some files but after that does't work.

Comment: well, then you probably need to look for the reason in your iPod client

Comment: Check in lines 42 and 53 what you're trying to access there. Make generous use of `print_r` to follow your program's internal state. Check what it's doing. **Debug.**

Comment: but pekka the errors are of php page not on ipod programing where should i plac print_r statement.

Answer (score 1):

The error message seems to be telling you that there is no such element at key "photo" in the global `$_FILES` array. That means the client didn't even send a file in the "photo" field.

As with any other input parameter, you should validate this condition before trying to access the element. For example, with: `if (isset($_FILES['photo'])) {...}`. And even when `$_FILES['photo']` is set, you should check `$_FILES['photo']['error']` for exceptions such as partial uploads (`UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL`) or empty uploads (`UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE`) as described in the [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).

You can debug this problem by adding the proper validations, i.e., making sure that the file upload exists and has been successful.